# dpkg-deb and file association

Tags: software-installation, dpkg

Is it possible to use dpkg-deb to create an installation package that associate a specific file extension to the installed application?

For example, let's say I'm distributing a program to manage image files and I'd like to associate -during the installation phase- *.jpg files to it. In this way, the user can double click on a .jpg file and open it with my program.

Currently I use the following command line to create the package:

`sudo dpkg-deb --build --root-owner-group --no-uniform-compression ./deb`

where the deb folder contains the program, the icon and the DEBIAN/control file.

Comment: Hello. App associations are in the OS so I do not think you can override or set that in the app. After installing your app the user can set the association.